# How to load JSON data in android when INTERNET Connection is Lost in android

Tags: android, json

I have the Android application that requires the internet connectivity to load the JSON data from internet and I want to show the local JSON data when the internet connectivity is lost.

Comment: Try to load the data over the internet and if it fails, return a saved copy of the last time it succeeded

Comment: In addition to when "internet connectivity is lost" you probably want to check if there is a route to the host, that dns didn't fail, that the server returned a json file and not a 404 or 500 or 302 or ...   Lots of ways a "get content from 'net" can fail and each should be accounted for

Answer (score 0):

So from your question it seems like you are looking to store json locally. Well if thats the case than there are two ways to do it.

1. Store it in [Sqlite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) database.
2. Store it in [Shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

I will suggest to go for Sqlite storage if your Json is large and multiple for different screens.

Answer (score 0):

save your local json data in a string file and parse it, for example

```
String json="{"name":"yourName","id":"yourId"}";
```

then to parse this use

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(json);
String name=jsonObject.optString("name");
String id=jsonObject.optString("id");
```